# Capacitor Camera not working throws localhost/vendor.js error. Ionic+Angular+firebase+androidstudio+capacitor

Tags: angular, android-studio, camera, capacitor, ionic5

Everything in my app is working properly on browser. Now when i try to emulate it on android studio and installing its apk on mobile, google sign in and camera wont work. When triggering the buttons (both camera and google sign in) it throws this error.

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File:http//localhost/vendor.js - Line 45885 - Msg: ERROR
```

during building it also throws this error, thought this maybe a part of the problem.

```
E/Capacitor: Unable to read file at path public/plugins
```

I tried every solution that I can find in the web, except some that I didn't understand because its so advanced. Here's my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.geof.ionic">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.geof.ionic.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Here's my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.geof.ionic"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

I tried making network_security_config.xml but still didn't work.

This is my code in trigerring camera:

```
async changeAvatar() {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
    });
    const loading = await this.loading.create();
    await loading.present();
    this.authService.uploadAvatar(image.base64String).subscribe((res) => {
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

And here's for google-sign in/up:

```
//service//
async googleSignup() {
    await GoogleAuth.init();
    const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      googleUser.authentication.idToken
    );
    const afUser = await this.afAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return this.updateUserData(
      afUser.user,
      googleUser.givenName,
      googleUser.imageUrl
    );
  }

//.ts file//
openGoogleSignup() {
    this.auth.googleSignup().then((res) => {
      this.close();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/app');
    }, err => {
      // Canceled the sign up
    });
  }
```

I tried making a new simple app for the camera, it wont work in android studio, but it worked properly when I installed it in mobile. I'm so lost and confused what the problem of my app is. Please Help me guys, this is my first-to-be-real-world-app. Good day everyone.